# Mixing HQL with criteria

Tags: c#, nhibernate

As far as I can tell there are a number of ways to access data in nhibernate; HQL, Criteria, linq to nhibernate and raw sql.

Is it possible in nhibernate to mix the query technoligies when accessing a data source. For example having a where clause as a (detached) criteria and the select or join as a HQL? Or any other combination of the above.

Comment: you mean in the same statement? ie appending a Criteria to an hql query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current preferred technologies are `Linq` and `QueryOver`, internally they map respectively on `HQL` and `Criteria`. You can use the one you feel more indicated in a project without any particular drawback, but of course you can't mix them in a single statement, ie you can't append a QueryOver to a Linq statement and vice-versa.